# Passing context to alert dialog in onReceivedSslError in SystemWebViewClient.java file cordova

Tags: android, cordova, sslerrorhandler

I want to display alert dialog in `onReceivedSslError` method of `SystemWebViewClient` class.So what should I pass parameter to alert dialog.I tried "`this`,`MainActivity.this`,`view.this`" but its not working.Thanks in advance.

Code currently i'm using

```
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, final SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Tab1Activity.this);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    String message = "SSL Certificate error.";
    switch (error.getPrimaryError()) {
        case SslError.SSL_UNTRUSTED:
            message = "The certificate authority is not trusted.";
            break;
        case SslError.SSL_EXPIRED:
            message = "The certificate has expired.";
            break;
        case SslError.SSL_IDMISMATCH:
            message = "The certificate Hostname mismatch.";
            break;
        case SslError.SSL_NOTYETVALID:
            message = "The certificate is not yet valid.";
            break;
    }

    message += " Do you want to continue anyway?";
    alertDialog.setTitle("SSL Certificate Error");
    alertDialog.setMessage(message);
    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Ignore SSL certificate errors
            handler.proceed();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            handler.cancel();
        }
    });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Issue is resolved after adding view.getContext() as parameter to alertDialog.builder object.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not something about the context you are passing, but you are trying to show the dialog from a place which isn't permitted.

You can either show a notification or create a showDialod() function in activity class and then call it from SystemWebViewClient class.

Hope it helps.